# Script tag not working ASP.NET core, webpack, typescript and knockout

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core, webpack, knockout.js

I have a solution made up of the above technologies. I am using knockout components made up of .html and .ts files. When trying a simple `<script>` tag on the .html file, nothing happens.

The component is payment-details.html and the code is as simple as follows:

```
<h1>Payment details</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("test");
</script>
```

The underlying payment-details.ts is:

```
import * as ko from 'knockout';

class PaymentDetailsViewModel {

    constructor() {
    }
}

export default { viewModel: PaymentDetailsViewModel, template: require('./payment-details.html')};
```

and the _Layout.cshtml file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] Contactless Check In</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what the issue is or where to start looking. There's something in the solution somewhere that is stopping script execution. Nor does it render in the html.

Thank you!

Comment: Wait, is the `h1` element in the resulting HTML?

Comment: I've tried this suggestion - thank you! But the only place it works higher up is in the Index.cshtml script section. This then loads the app-root.html component, the home-page.html component and then the payment-details.html component. None of which work with the script tag. There's no error displaying on the page either.

Comment: Yes the h1 element works

Comment: So to be clear, the `h1` element is in the resulting document but the `script` element that immediately follows it is not?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: oh this is really rather embarrassing, it's just started working... I can only assume that it was cached... I kid you not, i've spent a while restarting and refreshing the app and the page...

Comment: Well, have yourself a sigh of relief. You earned it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Apologies for the wasted time. Web development.